# how to use Debug Diagnostic Tool v2.0

Tags: windows, debugging, process, profiling, windbg

I am a beginner for debugging windows process and still learning process analysis and debuging . I have choosed to use  Debug Diagnostic Tool [v2.0] and planning to automate the process analysis/debug using this tool. Is there any good tutorial for this tool usage  ?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to automate the process analysis/debug using Debug Diagnostic Tool [v2.0] because it's a WinForms app and wrapper over [ClrMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime)  :

> a set of advanced APIs for programmatically inspecting a crash dump of
>   a .NET program much in the same way that the SOS Debugging Extensions
>   (SOS) do

Read the introduction post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx).

So assuming, you already have a dump, it's better to automate analysis using ClrMD.